# Should using the "new" keyword in the factories be avoided?

Tags: c++, memory, factory

As I went through our codebase, I saw using the `new` keyword for memory allocation in almost every factory. It makes perfect sense, and is OK until the users are disciplined and assigning created instances to the smart pointers (that are forced by our CS, or at last do proper memory management).

But digging deeper, I found out it is not that case every time, and we are assigning the returned instances to the raw pointers on multiple occasions without properly freeing them anywhere, and I feel like using the factories makes this even easier as it hides to some extent the allocation part.

Is there any possibility or tweak, how to use the factory, but assure that it is implemented as memory safe as possible? When I was thinking about it, it looks simple - just return a unique/shared pointer and the problem is solved, but this is already assuming that we know the exact usage of the instance from the ownership perspective.

So, to my question - should the memory allocation using the `new` be avoided even in factories? Is there a way how to solve this in an elegant way, and without relying on the caller of the create method to behave in a memory responsible way?

Comment: Sounds like Valgrind is going to have a field day with this code.

Comment: You should prefer `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` and avoid manual memory management applied by _"discipline"_.

Comment: Unless you can architect your classes to be cheap to copy and easily passed around by value, and you're not facing a lot of intense polymorphism, you're basically stuck with `new`. If you want, you can and probably should pick a pointer wrapper for that to make your life easier.

Comment: Compiler can detect memory management problems with smart pointers. Compiler can't detect memory management problems with `new` and raw pointers.  (And, given the track record, *discipline* is fraught with human error.)  In modern C++, I have not needed to use `new` for the last 11 years.

Comment: fwiw, a factory does not need to know if ownership will be shared or not. It returns a `unique_ptr` because at that point the caller is the unique owner, and then if they want, the caller can still turn it into a shared resource (see overload (13) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

Comment: raw `new` should be avoided. Factories are no exception. I don't understand why you think so

Comment: Rule of thumb:  dynamic allocation, a.k.a. `new`, should always be avoided if possible.  Dynamic allocation is always more complex than stack or global memory access.

Comment: Note that even if you return `std::unique_ptr`, caller can still adjust ownership to their needs (and use e.g. `std::shared_ptr` ) using `release()`. This is not a big issue.

Comment: Manual memory management (raw `new`/`delete`) is a *huge* red flag in modern C++ and should usually be avoided.

Comment: Even among the disciplined, there is often a lot can go wrong between `new` and protecting the instance with a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textbook solution is, of course, as πάντα ῥεῖ wrote: use a `T::create()` member function that returns either `std::unique_ptr<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<T>`, plus make ctors private; and that should work in most cases.

However, as you wrote, there are cases where you need an instance 'on the spot'. In such cases, the overhead of smart pointers (and heap allocation) is simply too much to pay, and in C++ we don't tend to pay for what we don't use. In such cases, you might ensure that an instance is created on the stack by accepting a 'visiting' lambda on the newly constructed instance:

```
class T
{
private:
    T() {}
    // other ctors, etc.

public:
    template<typename... Args>
    std::shared_ptr<T> create(Args&&... args) { return std::make_shared(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

    template<typename V, typename... Args>
    static void with_created(V v, Args&&... args)
    {
        T t;
        v(t); // v accepts T& or const T&
    }
};
```

Usage of the latter:

```
int main()
{
    T::with_created([&](T& t) {
        /* here you can manipulate t */
    }, /* ctor args of T */);
}
```

Comment: @MooingDuck It _is_ an overhead over ASDV (loosely speaking, stack allocation), due to the allocation - similarly to allocating by `new`. The method presented does not have the allocation overhead, either.

Comment: The overhead I was thinking of was something to do with the Itanium ABI requiring that the `unique_ptr` went on the stack and couldn't be passed by register. Is that the same thing you're saying? I'm outside my expertise here, so I'm unsure.

Comment: @MooingDuck No. What I'm saying is, when you return a `unique_ptr`, you necessarily alloc on the heap (well, unless you return nullptr, but meh). And heap allocation is extremely pricely (linked list iteration, update, etc.). The method `with_created()` constructs on the stack (to be precise, ASDV). This does not do heap allocation.

Comment: Ah, I half-see your point. How does a caller use `with_created`?

Comment: @MooingDuck Pass a lambda as the first argument, e.g. `T::with_created([&](T& t) { /* do what you'd like to do with t */ } /*, ctor args */);`

Comment: Ah, I can see how that would be useful for non-movable classes

Comment: @MooingDuck It's still ok if movable but move ctor is private. (In general, rule-of-five private)